# How to generate RSA public key with no any API. Just using modulus and public exponent

Tags: c++, c, rsa, public-key-encryption, public-key

How to generate RSA public key with no any API. Just using modulus and public exponent.

In our project we are implementing RSA PKCS#8 public key by modulus and public exponent.
However we don't know meaning of ASN.1 binary of PKCS#8 public key.

For understanding PKCS#8 public key ASN.1, we did blow.

```
 1. openssl genrsa -out hoge.key 2048  
 2. openssl rsa -pubout -in hoge.key  

Here we get below infomation.

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA7z2oyePt5vNbH7Pbieiw
BOgRnCUyyUvUo6Wi+uqUWvMxrji1vH21ViTZYLjg40RrulSCGFwjzwnI4AMtEdIZ
7uOol12E3xOZYNgwTBaDNCT9p0IYYuFVGfQyxlavr7oSIaaNmlSRy+0os1xi7IiI
PCHE/7nfifDQiqGtb6b6TBOwP3QXg5IdrXiqQJAlk+8S0XPhbnwwzWOhlrR3Wftq
jylBPSGSDJQoF0fJ5h2cA2yJiGqTV37YRTThPWmQEuz8Njx4bTaEaTul5/UNhSel
s7khd/IvHV9oN6T2o4V//fAsyjRZlYKEUHldb3ML/QHxWs7+hqWSa9NCwwXZGhEl
wwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

> 0000000 30 82 01 22 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01
0000010 01 05 00 03 82 01 0f 00 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01
0000020 00 ef 3d a8 c9 e3 ed e6 f3 5b 1f b3 db 89 e8 b0
0000030 04 e8 11 9c 25 32 c9 4b d4 a3 a5 a2 fa ea 94 5a
0000040 f3 31 ae 38 b5 bc 7d b5 56 24 d9 60 b8 e0 e3 44
0000050 6b ba 54 82 18 5c 23 cf 09 c8 e0 03 2d 11 d2 19
0000060 ee e3 a8 97 5d 84 df 13 99 60 d8 30 4c 16 83 34
0000070 24 fd a7 42 18 62 e1 55 19 f4 32 c6 56 af af ba
0000080 12 21 a6 8d 9a 54 91 cb ed 28 b3 5c 62 ec 88 88
0000090 3c 21 c4 ff b9 df 89 f0 d0 8a a1 ad 6f a6 fa 4c
00000a0 13 b0 3f 74 17 83 92 1d ad 78 aa 40 90 25 93 ef
00000b0 12 d1 73 e1 6e 7c 30 cd 63 a1 96 b4 77 59 fb 6a
00000c0 8f 29 41 3d 21 92 0c 94 28 17 47 c9 e6 1d 9c 03
00000d0 6c 89 88 6a 93 57 7e d8 45 34 e1 3d 69 90 12 ec
00000e0 fc 36 3c 78 6d 36 84 69 3b a5 e7 f5 0d 85 27 a5
00000f0 b3 b9 21 77 f2 2f 1d 5f 68 37 a4 f6 a3 85 7f fd
0000100 f0 2c ca 34 59 95 82 84 50 79 5d 6f 73 0b fd 01
0000110 f1 5a ce fe 86 a5 92 6b d3 42 c3 05 d9 1a 11 25
0000120 c3 02 03 01 00 01                              
0000126
```

we understand above binary as below. However we don't understand some binary.So We would like to know meaning of ASN.1 binary of PKCS#8 public key.
By the way, We have already refer below information. However this does not mention about public key.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5208

```
30: SEQUEENCE
82: next 2byte is sequence length 
01 22: 0x122byte
30: SEWUENCE
0d:?
06:?
09:?
2a 86.. 01 01 01: PKCS#1 rsa Encryption
05: ?
00: ?
03: ?
82: next 2byte is length of bit string
01 0f: length of bit string
00: ?
30 82....: PKCS#1 public key
```

Comment: _"How to generate RSA public key with no any API."_ read the __Key generation__ section https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem) You need to generate both public and private keys of the key-pair.

Comment: Please clarify your question. I suspect the use of the word "generate" is hitting a language barrier. It *looks* like you want to know how to extract the modulus and public exponent from a PEM-encoded RSA public key as shown, *without* using any OpenSSL or other crypto API to do it. If that is the case you need to be crystal clear in your question, as I suspect a volley of answers telling you how to genuinely generate a "new" key pair will be forthcoming.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a huge gamble that what you're *really* asking is how to obtain the modulus and public exponent from a RSA public key PEM encoding, I invite you on this tryst. If your looking to *build* this encoding given only the modulus and public exponent, this dissection should show you how it's laid out, and this a somewhat reverse roadmap to get there. Either way, read on.

First of all: *"next 2byte is length of bit string"* - that's rather assumptive of you. ASN.1 is all about  type-length-value (TLV for short) and *does not waver* from that model. The only reason the "next 2 byte is length of bit string" is because the ASN.1 said it is. (more on that later).

ASN.1 in incredibly flexible. I recently had a colleague jokingly tell me "ASN.1 is just JSON for boomers". Yeah, I took that personally. Since JSON followed ASN.1 by decades, I like to think "JSON is just ASN.1 for millennials".

Anyway, funny thing about ASN.1 (and JSON, for that matter): sometimes there are TLV encodings within TLV encodings, and that is the case here. Specifically an RSAPublicKey sequence will be encoded in an ASN.1 bit-string provided the setup is correct (i.e. the OID matches), and that seems to be the part you're struggling with: how to *find* it.

I'm going to leave the actual *code* to do this (which will be tedious, no-doubt fraught with hackery, and ultimately leave you wishing you had just used a crypto-library) as a task. That said, on to the act ripping apart your public key. First, your PEM:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA7z2oyePt5vNbH7Pbieiw
BOgRnCUyyUvUo6Wi+uqUWvMxrji1vH21ViTZYLjg40RrulSCGFwjzwnI4AMtEdIZ
7uOol12E3xOZYNgwTBaDNCT9p0IYYuFVGfQyxlavr7oSIaaNmlSRy+0os1xi7IiI
PCHE/7nfifDQiqGtb6b6TBOwP3QXg5IdrXiqQJAlk+8S0XPhbnwwzWOhlrR3Wftq
jylBPSGSDJQoF0fJ5h2cA2yJiGqTV37YRTThPWmQEuz8Njx4bTaEaTul5/UNhSel
s7khd/IvHV9oN6T2o4V//fAsyjRZlYKEUHldb3ML/QHxWs7+hqWSa9NCwwXZGhEl
wwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Decoding the base64 to DER, then displayed through xxd, it looks like this:

```
00000000: 30 82 01 22 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01  0.."0...*.H.....
00000010: 01 05 00 03 82 01 0f 00 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01  ........0.......
00000020: 00 ef 3d a8 c9 e3 ed e6 f3 5b 1f b3 db 89 e8 b0  ..=......[......
00000030: 04 e8 11 9c 25 32 c9 4b d4 a3 a5 a2 fa ea 94 5a  ....%2.K.......Z
00000040: f3 31 ae 38 b5 bc 7d b5 56 24 d9 60 b8 e0 e3 44  .1.8..}.V$.`...D
00000050: 6b ba 54 82 18 5c 23 cf 09 c8 e0 03 2d 11 d2 19  k.T..\#.....-...
00000060: ee e3 a8 97 5d 84 df 13 99 60 d8 30 4c 16 83 34  ....]....`.0L..4
00000070: 24 fd a7 42 18 62 e1 55 19 f4 32 c6 56 af af ba  $..B.b.U..2.V...
00000080: 12 21 a6 8d 9a 54 91 cb ed 28 b3 5c 62 ec 88 88  .!...T...(.\b...
00000090: 3c 21 c4 ff b9 df 89 f0 d0 8a a1 ad 6f a6 fa 4c  <!..........o..L
000000a0: 13 b0 3f 74 17 83 92 1d ad 78 aa 40 90 25 93 ef  ..?t.....x.@.%..
000000b0: 12 d1 73 e1 6e 7c 30 cd 63 a1 96 b4 77 59 fb 6a  ..s.n|0.c...wY.j
000000c0: 8f 29 41 3d 21 92 0c 94 28 17 47 c9 e6 1d 9c 03  .)A=!...(.G.....
000000d0: 6c 89 88 6a 93 57 7e d8 45 34 e1 3d 69 90 12 ec  l..j.W~.E4.=i...
000000e0: fc 36 3c 78 6d 36 84 69 3b a5 e7 f5 0d 85 27 a5  .6<xm6.i;.....'.
000000f0: b3 b9 21 77 f2 2f 1d 5f 68 37 a4 f6 a3 85 7f fd  ..!w./._h7......
00000100: f0 2c ca 34 59 95 82 84 50 79 5d 6f 73 0b fd 01  .,.4Y...Py]os...
00000110: f1 5a ce fe 86 a5 92 6b d3 42 c3 05 d9 1a 11 25  .Z.....k.B.....%
00000120: c3 02 03 01 00 01                                ......
```

Regular ASN.1 encoding, as expected. For a PKCS8 encoded key, it should look like this:

```
PublicKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
  algorithm       AlgorithmIdentifier,
  PublicKey       BIT STRING
}
```

Sending our base64-decoded DER data through ASN.1 decoding, we see::

```
openssl asn1parse -in pubkey.der -inform DER

    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
    6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   19:d=1  hl=4 l= 271 prim: BIT STRING
```

That looks about right. For an RSA public key, the OID is 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1, the NULL, then what should be a RSAPublicKey as the PublicKey key data bit-string, which will look like this:

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
}
```

From the aforementioned decoding, we know at offset 19 is the actual bit string, which *should* contain the RSAPublicKey ASN.1 structure. Great, but how? Well, the original parse has the following at offset-19 of the file:

```
00000010: 01 05 00 03 82 01 0f 00 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01  ........0.......
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

From this we get:

- The ASN.1 tag byte, `03`, says its a bit-string. Good. We expected that. then...
- The length is calculated. Per ASN.1 rules, if the length octet has the high bit lit, it means the remaining bits of that octet tell how many subsequent octets make up the actual length (i.e it can be a multi-byte length). `82` means two octets follow, indicating
  the bit-string overall object length: `010f`, e.g. 271 bytes.
- Immediately following the length description will be a single octet stating the number of *padding bits* of the bit-string. I can honestly say in a quarter century of staring at these I have *never* seen this any value other than zero (`00`) in any RSA encoded public key, but still worth mentioning.

Thereafter is the actual RSAPublicKey ASN.1 structure itself. Past the bit-string type-length-padding description, we can parse the actual RSAPublicKey (finally!). The bit-string content after the type-length and padding bits indicator should be just that. Well, that's at offset 24 of our DER-encoding, so:

```
openssl asn1parse -in pubkey.der -inform DER -offset 24

    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim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
  265:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001
```

Sure enough, there it is, the modulus and the exponent as expected. Extracting and decoding from there is just a matter of code, but at least now it is code based on decoding by calculation and not guessing.

**Fair Warning**

The *only* reason why this worked is because we knew the RSAPublicKey was in the bit string, and the *only* reason we knew that was because the OID says it was. The form stored in the bit-string is dependent on that OID, so make sure to check it *first* before assuming the bit-string is RSAPublicKey material.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to generate a public key, but I don't understand why you show some binary data you are trying to decode. You can not learn how to generate a public or private key from looking at binary data which i assume is already encrypted.
Why not use a library to generate a key pair and be done with it? Trying to code something yourself, from scratch, is likely (very likely in fact) to have errors which lead to really insecure conditions.
In any event, you can download the source code to ssl libraries like openssl if you want to see what you can learn from them.